# Unity IoC throws invalid cast exception

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, unity-container

I'm trying to register a generic interface / implementation via Unity IoC, but the constructor parameter in the ViewModel, throws an invalid cast exception, and I cannot figure out why.

I have an interface, which all models implement:

```
public interface IEntity {}
```

A typical model would look like this:

```
public class Dashboard: IEntity { .... }
```

I have a database service, which can be of any model type, and an associated interface, for example:

```
public interface IDbService<T> where T: IEntity { .... }

public class DbService<T> where T : IEntity, IDbService<T> { .... }
```

The container registration looks like this:

```
container.RegisterType(typeof(IDbService<>), typeof(DbService<>));
```

which works up to this point.

However, when I try and load this into my ViewModel class, I get an invalid cast exception, my implementation on the constructor, for argument sake, in the DashboardPageViewModel, which looks like this:

```
private readonly IDbService<Dashboard> _dbService;

public DashboardPageViewModel(IDbService<Dashboard> dbService)
{
     _dbService = dbService;
}
```

This throws the exception.

Why can I not cast Dashboard to  in this regard? Trying to resolve the cast after I've registered the type, does not work either.

Answer (score 2):

The class has been defined incorrectly.

In

```
public class DbService<T> where T : IEntity, IDbService<T> { .... }
```

`DbService<T>` only has type constraints where `T` is derived from `IEntity` and also `IDbService<T>`

You need to have the class derived from `IDbService<T>` interface and then apply the generic type constraint.

```
public interface IDbService<T> where T: IEntity { .... }

public class DbService<T> : IDbService<T> where T : IEntity { .... }
```